# Этимология слова "априори"

Tags: этимология

В каких случаях употребляется слово "априори"

Comment: Это давно уже слово-паразит. Прекрасно можно обойтись без него. Но большие философы и ученые... в своих научных трудах... пусть употребляют, если невтерпеж.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.Совершенно с вами согласна.

Answer (score 2):

Вас этимология интересует или значение?

> АПРИОРИ, нареч. [лат. a priori].
> 1. Филос., лог.
> Независимо от опыта, до опыта (противоп.: апостериори). Нельзя решать этот вопрос а.
> 2. Не проверяя, не устанавливая чего-л. заранее, предварительно.

(БТС, Кузнецова)

На мой взгляд - исчерпывающе.

Answer (score 2):

Рrior — первый, старший, первоначальный. Например, приоритéт — понятие, показывающее важность, первенство.

ЭТО ИНТЕРЕСНО

"Первое использование термина восходит к античности. Аристотель (384—322 гг. до н. э.) первым употребил его для обозначения области знания, изучающей преимущественно духовную сторону человеческой природы (в настоящее время этим занимается психология). С этим значением термин просуществовал свыше тысячелетия. Сохранилось оно и до сих пор, например, в религиозном знании (теологии), в философии, во многих гуманитарных науках (например, в искусствознании), а отчасти и в самой психологии".

ИЗ ВИКИПЕДИИ

Априо́ри (лат. a priori — буквально «от предшествующего») — знание, как бы заранее известное. Этот философский термин получил важное значение в теории познания и логике благодаря Канту. Идея знания априори связана с представлением о внутреннем источнике активности мышления. Учение, признающее знание априори, называется априоризмом. Противоположностью априори является апостериори (лат. a posteriori — от последующего) — знание, полученное из опыта (опытное знание).

"Проблема соотношения априорного и апостериорного знания имеет глубокие истоки и восходит к вопросу возникновения человека и всего живого. Если человек является частью, этапом  эволюции материи, тогда в нем с необходимостью заложено генетическое знание истории его собственного развития, которое при определенных условиях служит основой его социализации. Но если человек есть уникальное и спонтанное образование,тогда его знание есть приобретенное, опытное".

Термин имеет долгую историю и не раз менял своё значение. Вне философского контекста это выражение часто употребляется как синоним «первоначально», «бездоказательно», «умозрительно», «предварительно». Например: Это численное тождество, которое априори достоверно.Однако знать об этом совершенно априори он все же не мог.

Comment: София, а просто ссылки на Википедию было не достаточно?
Хотя лично я даже не стал на неё вообще ссылаться, ибо не по теме, мы не философией тут занимаемся.

Answer (score 1):

Полностью согласен с [@behemothus](/users/445/behemothus). Но хотелось бы дополнить. Первоначальное значение, приведенное в ответе, с течением времени как-то перетекло в производное. Сначала считалось, что априори делать чего-то НЕ следует, то есть, надо поставить опыт и только после этого убедиться в правильности мнения. Сейчас всё чаще приходится слышать вариант в значении, что мнение **априори правильное** и не требует проверки на практике. Полагаю, это не ошибка, но оттенок совсем другой. Но встречается и такой неверный вариант употребления: "Вы нас тут всех априори выслушали...",- то есть, в значении обобщения, объединения "под одну гребёнку". Страшно безграмотно, но почему-то в народе живёт...

Comment: Подождите, подождите...
Какой-такой *опыт* надо *поставить*?
Исторически это терминология античных философов и, если не ошибаюсь, римского права. В те времена ни о каких постановках опытовпросто не слышали. Опыт - это прежде всего накопленные знания.  
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%EE%EF%FB%F2&all=x
  
Потом уже проросло в научную терминологию.

Comment: Хорошо, не поставить опыт, а убедиться на примере полученного опыта.

Answer (score 0):

А вот и подсказка: АПРИОРИ, нареч. [лат. a priori]. А что за слово priori? Например дошедшее до нас "Приорат". Один из вариантов - власть - следовательно: без разрешения.